# Creating a large integer in Julia

Tags: julia

I am learning Julia and I would like to create an object in Julia that contains just a single large integer, for example, 1100000. What I could do is write `n = 1.1e6` but then the type of this object is `Float64` and if I want to use it as an argument for `rand()`, I get an error message because the object is not an integer. So instead what I do is as follows.

```
n = Int64(1.1e6)
rand(n)
```

But it seems that I am changing the type of the variable here (from `Float64` to `Int64`) and this should be avoided in Julia as far as I understand. Of course I could use `n = 1100000` but this is inefficient and difficult to read in my opinion.

Am I changing the type of the variable here? If yes, is this a good way to change the type of the variable or is there a better way to create an integer using scientific notation without having to change the type of the variable?

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Writing `n = 1100000` is not inefficient. It is in fact _optimally_ efficient. For readability, you can do better, by adding underscores.

Comment: @DNF Thank you for your comment. What I had in mind is that it is inefficient from the writing point of view (we would have to count the zeros by hand). Adding underscores improves readability but if I have an even larger integer, say, `n = 1100_000_000_000`, it is not that readable anymore. So I am wondering if there is a better way to create such integers without actually having to write all the zeros by hand. I guess another option could be to write `n = 10^12 + 10^11` but then this results in a small expression that needs to be evaluated and I am not sure if it is that readable.

Comment: I guess my only suggestion then is `11 * 10^11`.

Answer (score 6):

I would write it as:

```
n = 1_100_000
```

for me it is more readable than

```
n = Int(1.1e6)
```

(or even `1.1e6`) but of course it is subjective.

Changing type like in `Int(1.1e6)` is not a problem in Julia. It will work, as long as passed float represents an integer (otherwise you will get `InexactError` error).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It seems that we should [avoid changing the type of a variable](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/performance-tips/#Avoid-changing-the-type-of-a-variable). It is not a problem here but we should be careful if this is a part of a loop as in the example in the link, where the type gets changed over and over, right?

Comment: In that case, you are not changing the value of any variable. You are just passing around values and assigning the result to a variable.

Comment: @phipsgabler Do you mean in the example in the link? First, `x = 1` is created which is an `Int64`. Once `x /= rand()`, the type of `x` becomes `Float64` and this is a problem for the compiler. But in my example the variable `n` is created as `Int64` right away and this would not be a problem even if it was inside a function. Do I understand correctly?

Comment: No, I meant `n = Int(1.1e6)`. Your understanding is correct.

Comment: Actually doing `x=1` and then e.g. `x=1.0` inside a function is only a minor problem for the compiler. I.e. it will have a performance penalty, but small. The reason is that Julia compiler is smart enough to understand that `x` can take have two types and optimize against this case. The biggest problem would be if the compiler would have to assume that `x` has e.g. `Any` type (because then it cannot optimize code execution against this case). Having said that, it is best, as you have said, not to change type of value bound to some variable in performance sensitive code.